# Test Cognito results locally?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

AWS Cognito doesn't accept localhost as signin url. My app is hosted on S3 and behind a CloudFrnot distribution, so we can get https url. I'm using [amazon-cognito-auth-js](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-auth-js) to do authentication on my app. Even if I run my app locally, after authentication, it will redirect me to my cloudfront url, and I need to check logs from Chrome developer tool. So for any change / test, I need to build my app, and upload it on S3, use a new inognito sesison on my browser. I'm wondering is there an easier way to do local development with Cognito? Is there any way to redirect Cognito to localhost and do local test there? Any other idea is welcomed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found the answer: you can add http://localhost:3000 as callback url (sign in) into your User Pool App client. You can either create a new app client for this purpose, or add a new callback url (comma separated) to existing app; each user pool client app can have multiple call back urls.

Comment: what about redirect_uri ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use localhost to test out cognito. The problem is that cognito doesn't allow HTTP. If you install an IIS certificate on you computer to use HTTPS on your machine, you will be able to use that as callback url. A tutorial for doing this is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/install/installing-iis-7/installing-iis-on-windows-vista-and-windows-7)